# Groupby on multiple Columns

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, linq, visual-studio

I have a DataTable on which i want to convert it to the list

```
 var rows = cableDataTable.AsEnumerable()                            
 .Select((x) =>
  new
  {
     TagGroup = x.Field<string>("TagNo"),
     RowNo = (i == 0) ? (j++).ToString() : "",
     TagNo = x.Field<string>("TagNo"),
     FromBayPanel = x.Field<string>("FromBayPanel"),                                     
     Size = x.Field<string>("CoreSize"),
     Type = x.Field<string>("Type"),
     FromBay = x.Field<string>("FromBay"),
     FromPanel = x.Field<string>("FromPanel"),
     CoreNo = x.Field<string>("CoreNo") == DBNull.Value.ToString() ? "" : x.Field<string>("CoreNo"),
     RealCoreNo = x.Field<int>("RealCoreNo"),                                 
     FromDevice = x.Field<string>("FromDevice") == DBNull.Value.ToString() ? "" : x.Field<string>("FromDevice"),                                 
     FromTerminal = x.Field<string>("FromTerminal") == DBNull.Value.ToString() ? "" : x.Field<string>("FromTerminal"),
     FromRef = x.Field<string>("FromRef") == DBNull.Value.ToString() ? "" : x.Field<string>("FromRef"),
     ToBay = x.Field<string>("ToBay"),
     ToPanel = x.Field<string>("ToPanel"),
     ToDevice = x.Field<string>("ToDevice") == DBNull.Value.ToString() ? "" : x.Field<string>("ToDevice"),                                
     ToTerminal = x.Field<string>("ToTerminal") == DBNull.Value.ToString() ? "" : x.Field<string>("ToTerminal"),
     ToRef = x.Field<string>("ToRef") == DBNull.Value.ToString() ? "" : x.Field<string>("ToRef"),
     Remark = x.Field<string>("Remark") == DBNull.Value.ToString() ? "" : x.Field<string>("Remark"),
                             }).ToList();
```

I want to have to groupby the DataTable on multiple Columns. but when i do like this

1) How can I do that?

2) One more question is it better to convert the DBNull value on SQL Server side(by isNull command) or client side?

Comment: `Field<T>` always returns `null` when the underlying value is `DbNull.Value` (and the column data type is a nullable type).

Answer (score 1):

```
var resultSet= dataTable.GroupBy(e=> new { e.Column1, e.Column2 });
```

Comment: I cannot find any cableDataTable.GroupBy

Comment: What is the type of cableDataTable?

Comment: @nnmmss you must use `AsEnumerable` between `cableDataTable` and `GroupBy`.. like this:  `cableDataTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(...)`

Comment: ok that's what i said, after Groupby i can not use for example TagGroup = x.Field<string>("TagNo")  . There is no Field property for x.

Comment: @nnmmss, See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

After GroupBy you need to use aggregate function like sum , just like it is in sql.

```
           var resultSet = dataTable.GroupBy(e => new { e.Column1, e.Column2 }).Select(a => new { key1 = a.Key.Column1, Key2 = a.Key.Column2, TotalSize = a.Sum(b => b.Size), ConCatenatedTagGroups  = a.Select(c => c.TagGroup ).Aggregate((d, e) => d + e)});
```

Comment: thanks Mokchhya, I was looking for a clue on just this.  Any idea on how you'd push the result back into a DataTable?